# Function to change action attribute of form - gives 'undefined is not a function'

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to set the action attribute of a form depending on which button is clicked to exit a page, once the action is changed, the form should be submitted and the action then completed.

My jQuery function:

```
function changeAction(formAction) {
  ('#_21').attr('action', formAction);
  document.getElementById('_21').submit();    
  }
```

is called by an inline 'onclick' reference:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeAction('?page=myurl');">            
    <div class="text-save">Save and continue</div>     
    <div class="continue"></div>            
</a>
```

The idea being that I can pass the paramater I've named 'formAction' depending on which of several buttons are clicked.

On click however, console records the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Against the line in my function:

```
 ('#_21').attr('action', formAction);
```

Where am I going wrong? - Thanks

Comment: You're missing the `$` in `$('#_21')`..

Comment: put `$` like  `$('#_21').attr('action', formAction);`

Comment: Can downvoters comment on what is wrong with my question please?

Comment: @Gideon I would suspect it's a question about a simple typo. The error `undefined is not a function` on that line should have made the missing `$` immediately obvious. Just my guess on why there are on downvotes. This question is very unlikely to be useful to anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`('#_21')` is just the string value `#_21`. It doesn't have an `attr` method.

You're missing the dollar sign:

```
function changeAction(formAction) {
    $('#_21').attr('action', formAction);
    $('#_21').submit();    
}
```

or with method chaining:

```
function changeAction(formAction) {
    $('#_21').attr('action', formAction).submit();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeAction(formAction) {
  $('#_21').attr('action', 'formAction');
  $('#_21').submit();    
  }
```

Use this code i suggest you use  either jquery or raw javascript and not both at once